# Dynamically created button gets automatically fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dynamic unordered custom List view. In each element, there is one button. I am creating the list elements in the following way:

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayID.length; i++) {
    var listElement = '<li class="has-form">' +
        '<div class="row collapse">' +
        '<div class="small-1 columns" style="margin: 5px">' +
        '<img src="image/twitter.png">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="small-6 columns small-only-text-center">' +
            '<p>' +
                '<i>' + arrayText[i] + '</i>' +
            '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="small-3 columns">' +
            '<button type="button" class="large-10" onclick="' + onClickViewButton() + '">view</button>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="small-1 columns">' +
            '<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</li>';
    $("#myList").append(listElement);
}
```

The code for button click is:

```
function onClickViewButton() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

But unfortunately the when the page is loading, the button click is fired and not working on actual button click. 
Please help.

Comment: Replace `onclick="' + onClickViewButton() + '"`  with `onclick="onClickViewButton()"`

Comment: The explanation for the above fix is that the JS function is being called there. It just needs to be a string until the DOM interprets the element.

Answer (score 3):

Where you have:

```
onclick="'+onClickViewButton()+'"
```

you need to have:

```
onclick="onClickViewButton()"
```

instead.

Your current code calls the `onClickViewButton` function in your declaration, when what you really want to do is to just use it as a function reference so it gets called later on `onclick`.

Comment: Still need the `()` :D

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks a lot. Solved the issue with your solution

Comment: @user3577669 Glad I was able to solve your issue! Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this snippet:

> If you concat function name with parenthesis then it will be treated as function execution hence function will get called.

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayID.length; i++) {
  var listElement = '<li class="has-form">' +
    '<div class="row collapse">' +
    '<div class="small-1 columns" style="margin: 5px">' +
    '<img src="image/twitter.png">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="small-6 columns small-only-text-center">' +
    '<p>' +
    '<i>' + arrayText[i] + '</i>' +
    '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="small-3 columns">' +
    '<button type="button" class="large-10" onclick="onClickViewButton()">view</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="small-1 columns">' +
    '<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>';
  $("#myList").append(listElement);
}
```